# Socket server accepts only first call

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote a simple client-server app in c#. Everything works good, but the server only accepts first call of the client and no more. I tried to put the receive method in the loop too (as acceptTcpSocket method), but it's still the same.

**Simplified server code:**

```
public class XMLServer
{
    public void start()
    {
        server = new TcpListener(_serverIP, _serverPort);

        try
        {
            server.Start();
        }
        catch (SocketException socketError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(socketError.Message);
        }
    }
    public void listen()
    {
        try
        {
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            while (true)
            {
                receiveFromClient();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
    }

    public void receiveFromClient()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        byte[] send;
        int readed;

        stream = client.GetStream();
        readed = stream.Read(bytes, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        if (readed > 0)
        {
            string[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Split(':');

            Console.WriteLine(request[0]);
            switch (request[0])
            {
                case "getFileList":
                    send = encode(XMLFile.getFileList());

                    if (stream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        stream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
                    }
                    break;
                case "getFile":
                    send = encode(XMLFile.getFile(request[1]));

                    if (stream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        stream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using server code:**

```
XMLServer server = new XMLServer("10.0.0.5", "7777");
server.start();

while (true)
{
    server.listen();
}
```

**Client code:**

```
public partial class Client : Form
{
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;

    public Client(TcpClient parentClient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = parentClient;
        getFileList();
    }

    private void getFileList()
    {
        byte[] fileList = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("getFileList:null");
        byte[] fileListResponse;
        string[] files;
        int Y = 30;

        stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(fileList, 0, fileList.Length);

        fileListResponse = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        stream.Read(fileListResponse, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        files = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileListResponse).Split(';');

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            radioButton.Text = file;
            radioButton.Location = new Point(10, Y);

            groupBoxFiles.Controls.Add(radioButton);
            Y += 30;
        }
    }

    private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fileName = groupBoxFiles.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked).Text;
        byte[] getFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("getFile:" + fileName);
        byte[] getFileResponse;
        string fileContent;

        stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(getFile, 0, getFile.Length);

        getFileResponse = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        stream.Read(getFileResponse, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        fileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(getFileResponse);

        textBoxEditor.Enabled = true;
        textBoxEditor.Text = fileContent;
    }
}
```

First I call `XMLFile.getFileList` and Iít works good. Then I want to call `XMLFile.getFile`, after that the app stops.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you also post (at least the relevant part of) the client code?

Comment: Client code is added.

Comment: One more question: how does `XMLFile.getFileList()` return the files (in what form)? In other words can you post the file name - the label of the `RadioButton` that you selected in order to get the its content?

Comment: It returns all files from directory "D:\xmlFiles" as string. Each file is separated by semicolon. Eg. "Test1.xml;test2.xml". I think the problem is in the server. It's implemented wrong, but I don't know where.

Comment: Stupid question...in `listen()`, how does it ever get out of the `while` loop?  It only accepts the first connection because code execution never returns to the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Hmm, at the beginning i thought that the file request looked like `getFile:D:\xmlFiles\someFile.xml`(server ignoring  the part after the driveletter but i was wrong). How does the app(i assume it's the server) stop? any error, message, etc? is the `getFile` text displayed on the server app  screen? Can you also try printing to console the filename recived from the client? I assume that `XmlFile.getFile` prepends folder name to the argument.

Comment: Hint: Store the "client" returned by `AcceptTcpClient()` in a List<> and pass it to another thread.  Now start your receiving loop from that other thread.  This will free up your main thread so it can receive other connections...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I don't want my server accepts multiple user connections. I want to handle one client now using a one socket to send/receive multiple times. Currently after first request the server is blocked, but no exception is thrown.

Comment: @CristiFati In XMLFIle class everything is ok. If i change the order of calls and the first will be getFile it will be called properly. The problem is that the server is blocked after first request. I can't send two request to the same socket.

Comment: Your code is broken in the same way that so much code written by people new to networking and who haven't bothered to actually study the vast quantity of samples, tutorials, and documentation that exists: you are assuming that one read operation corresponds to one send operation, and you are ignoring the number of bytes actually read from the socket. Lacking [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, a specific answer can't be provided, but you really just need to go back and study the documentation more closely.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the code could be improved in many ways, but as I look at it it should work. So i have a couple of questions: what does "_the app is stopped_" actually mean? (i am assuming the app is the server) It freezes? It terminates?(if it does, what's the exit code?) Any error displayed?, Also what happens with the client app? How many xml files are in the folder? What's the (average) size of an xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the single root cause, but at least there is a conceptual problem: the result of the [Stream.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) call, the actual number of bytes read, is ignored.

> The send/receive functions of socket **does not guarantee** that all the data you provided will be sent/received at one call. The functions return actual number of sent/received bytes.
>
> -- [TCP/IP client-server application: exchange with string messages, Sergey Brunov](http://brunov.info/blog/2013/02/09/tcpip-client-server-application-exchange-with-string-messages/).

Also, please note:

> You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and receiving data. Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream.
>
> -- [TcpClient.GetStream Method, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).